# How can I stop my UHD screen from warping non UHD aware programs?

Tags: windows-8, high-resolution

I have a Lenovo T540p with a UHD screen it resolution is 3K. I am having an issue where not all of the software I run is UHD aware or capable at this time. Most notably VMware Player and few others. When I run the software the screen has really small text and the window is almost impossible to read or use.

I have tried dropping the resolution to something more reasonable like 1080p (1920x1080) but the issue is this is not the native resolution of the screen and it distorts everything.

Is there anything I can do to preserve the screen resolution but force the windows to scale up or cause the screen to scale down?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the DPI?

Comment: I have not, how would i do that? and would it affect the way the screen displays 1920x1080?

Comment: Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display` then select `Medium` or `Large`.

Comment: The DPI would be useful if you could set it per application, but it's not really a good fix for this situation. You could try the compatibility mode "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" under the shortcuts Properties.

Comment: The resolution 2880x1620 isn't UHD at all. UHD is fixed at 3840x2160, which is four times F(ull)HD at 1920x1080. What the proper name for your resolution is, though, nobody knows, because it's listed nowhere in summaries of commonly used display resolutions.